# Django Query - Annotate With Boolean Value From Date Comparison

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to write a query which will have an annotation of expired based on a comparison of a date in the model and the date/time of now and receive a boolean value depending on the outcome. I can't find how this is done.

I have tried the below so far:

```
.annotate(expired=F( F('date_updated') > datetime_now))
```

Can someone let me know the way to achive this?

Comment: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/annotate-a-condition-as-booleanfield.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can annotate the objects with a `BooleanField` that is the result of a condition with an
[**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    expired=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(date_updated__gt=datetime_now),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check manual for `extra/select` expressions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra
and do it like this:

```
Entry.objects.extra(select={'expired': "date_updated < '2006-01-01'"})
```